# rkhunter reports change in file properties, but I don't see that they've been updated by yum

Tags: yum, hacking, update, packages, rkhunter

Maybe I'm being overcautious, but I recently received the following warnings from rkhunter:

```
Warning: The file properties have changed:
        File: /bin/dmesg
        Current hash: e94b12f49e53695bf5161a445c00b3f97e37e9a8
        Stored hash : 4cc922b102987beea5ec3e10f283b08cfd942658
        Current file modification time: 1263983792 (20-Jan-2010 05:36:32)
        Stored file modification time : 1252007551 (03-Sep-2009 15:52:31)
Warning: The file properties have changed:
        File: /bin/kill
        Current hash: 12f2d4e21474ccdb989c9ee4d4102917e51d8d7b
        Stored hash : 8e14ca5dbdc158a833c2d861bf682e31aae24675
        Current file modification time: 1263983792 (20-Jan-2010 05:36:32)
        Stored file modification time : 1252007551 (03-Sep-2009 15:52:31)
Warning: The file properties have changed:
        File: /bin/logger
        Current hash: 08f2886e3ef1fa5adb34ed8b24477362206f85c6
        Stored hash : c2bf21ac162bc7de5f6c0b787c304707127e5d96
        Current file modification time: 1263983792 (20-Jan-2010 05:36:32)
        Stored file modification time : 1252007551 (03-Sep-2009 15:52:31)
Warning: The file properties have changed:
        File: /bin/login
        Current hash: d05eb12a1184d3babcf3380674293974b8a2dcce
        Stored hash : 4849447380595bbff3aacc1a1ac90e59f7289ca6
        Current file modification time: 1263983792 (20-Jan-2010 05:36:32)
        Stored file modification time : 1252007551 (03-Sep-2009 15:52:31)
Warning: The file properties have changed:
        File: /bin/more
        Current hash: e2bad443495de0c23be2f87f836f80eafa3ba330
        Stored hash : afb55b42873a210a5cec07baa106faa3829cae41
        Current file modification time: 1263983792 (20-Jan-2010 05:36:32)
        Stored file modification time : 1252007551 (03-Sep-2009 15:52:31)
Warning: The file properties have changed:
        File: /bin/mount
        Current hash: cfda891d89dc57c94327bd62845f8ef13c42ff54
        Stored hash : 32d8659bad80b43acc4e437510a88491c9c53294
        Current file modification time: 1263983789 (20-Jan-2010 05:36:29)
        Stored file modification time : 1252007547 (03-Sep-2009 15:52:27)
Warning: The file properties have changed:
        File: /usr/bin/kill
        Current hash: 12f2d4e21474ccdb989c9ee4d4102917e51d8d7b
        Stored hash : 8e14ca5dbdc158a833c2d861bf682e31aae24675
        Current file modification time: 1264059189 (21-Jan-2010 02:33:09)
        Stored file modification time : 1256283752 (23-Oct-2009 03:42:32)
Warning: The file properties have changed:
        File: /usr/bin/logger
        Current hash: 08f2886e3ef1fa5adb34ed8b24477362206f85c6
        Stored hash : c2bf21ac162bc7de5f6c0b787c304707127e5d96
        Current file modification time: 1264059189 (21-Jan-2010 02:33:09)
        Stored file modification time : 1256283752 (23-Oct-2009 03:42:32)
Warning: The file properties have changed:
        File: /usr/bin/whereis
        Current hash: 0d700404e6cfd49bc1ef39465a586706b3b9f008
        Stored hash : 1552446e1285fd3d361e0198149e0a946ee7f28b
        Current file modification time: 1263983792 (20-Jan-2010 05:36:32)
        Stored file modification time : 1252007551 (03-Sep-2009 15:52:31)
Warning: The file properties have changed:
        File: /sbin/nologin
        Current hash: 01b82549a312108b655cca21993d2b24a56f3c7e
        Stored hash : 61255119451e25eb27e6e9a4ca67219564896d4f
        Current file modification time: 1263983792 (20-Jan-2010 05:36:33)
        Stored file modification time : 1252007551 (03-Sep-2009 15:52:31)
Warning: The file properties have changed:
        File: /usr/sbin/vipw
        Current hash: da7bc573ef2c55f1f7e1a7ebb964dbf1187c2702
        Stored hash : dc50bdcb381833d6e8e12cc7af81b37a0b3c4c8e
        Current file modification time: 1263983792 (20-Jan-2010 05:36:32)
        Stored file modification time : 1252007551 (03-Sep-2009 15:52:31)
```

Normally, I check the yum logs to see if these files had recently been updated, but I don't see that they have:

```
Jan 21 02:33:08 Updated: 30:bind-libs-9.3.6-4.P1.el5_4.2.x86_64
Jan 21 02:33:08 Updated: perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib-2.024-1.el5.rf.x86_64
Jan 21 02:33:08 Updated: perl-Compress-Raw-Bzip2-2.024-1.el5.rf.x86_64
Jan 21 02:33:09 Updated: 30:bind-9.3.6-4.P1.el5_4.2.x86_64
Jan 21 02:33:09 Updated: 1:cups-libs-1.3.7-11.el5_4.5.x86_64
Jan 21 02:33:11 Updated: util-linux-2.13-0.52.el5_4.1.x86_64
Jan 21 02:33:11 Updated: gzip-1.3.5-11.el5.centos.1.x86_64
Jan 21 02:33:11 Updated: perl-IO-Compress-2.024-1.el5.rf.noarch
Jan 21 02:33:16 Updated: 30:caching-nameserver-9.3.6-4.P1.el5_4.2.x86_64
Jan 21 02:33:18 Updated: kernel-headers-2.6.18-164.11.1.el5.x86_64
Jan 21 02:33:18 Updated: 1:cups-libs-1.3.7-11.el5_4.5.i386
```

Am I missing something when I look at the log file? Would one of those packages result in the update of all of those packages?  Maybe util-linux?

I know running rkhunter --propupd will reset the base file info that it scans for, but I just want to make sure that I shouldn't be worried about these results first.  The packages that were altered seem like they could be utilized in a hacking attempt.

running last does not show any suspicious logins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just used the command "yum provides /path/binary" on a 64bit CentOS box I have here and all of those binaries are part of the util-linux package.  Which is listed in your recent updates.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that you have used ''prelink'' at some point between now and 3rd September 2009.  Prelink has a MD5 flag:

```
--md5
```

This is similar to --verify option, except instead of outputing the content of the 
binary or library before prelinking to standard output MD5 digest is printed. See md5sum(1).

Check those binaries with that, it should then match your recorded value if it's prelink causing them to change.